# tbls(データベースドキュメントを自動生成するOSSのツール)のエラー解決について教えてください。

Tags: macos, database, sqlite

## はじめに tblsを用いたDBドキュメント作成

[tbls](https://github.com/k1LoW/tbls)というツールを用いて既に存在しているDBのデータベース定義書を作成しようとしました.
まず,GitHubのREADME.mdに従い下記のようなファイル(.tbls.yml)を作成しました.

```
# .tbls.yml

# DSN (Database Source Name) to connect database
dsn: sqlite:///./db.sqlite3

# Path to generate document
docPath: ./dbdoc
```

また,これに加え同じディレクトリに(DBドキュメントを入れるための)dbdocというディレクトリを作成し,下記のコマンドをterminalで実行しました.

```
mkdir dbdoc
tbls doc
```

しかしこのコマンドを実行した結果"unable to open database file: no such file or directory"というエラーが出ます.

## 質問したいこと

上記で発生したエラーの原因及び解決策についてご教示いただきたいです.

## 補足その1 環境

OS:MacOSCatalina(ver 10.15.5)
DB:SQLite3
その他:DjangoのPJです

## 補足その2 私のディレクトリ構造

- カレントディレクトリ
  ~/Desktop/hoge_project(仮名)
- カレントディレクトリ下のファイル
  accounts document manage.py requirements.txt fuga(仮名) templates
  static .git **.tbls.yml** **db.sqlite3**

## 補足その3 参考にしたサイト

[公式ドキュメント(GitHub)](https://github.com/k1LoW/tbls)
[tblsを使って既存データベースからデータベース定義書をMarkdownで出力する方法 - note](https://note.com/dafujii/n/n6e328d29d33f)

補足必要箇所等ありましたらご指摘のほどお願い致します。
また、こうかもしれないレベルであっても構いませんので回答いただけると幸いです！
以上、よろしくお願いします！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

twitterでアドバイスいただいて解決したので載せます。
.tbls.ymlの `/` スラッシュを一つ減らせば解決です。

```yaml
# DSN (Database Source Name) to connect database
[False]  dsn: sqlite:///./db.sqlite3
[Correct]dsn: sqlite://./db.sqlite3
```

おそらくですが「`sqlite://` はプロトコルの指定(`http://` と一緒)」ということなのでは…と思います。
※パスは相対パスでも絶対パスでもどっちでもOKでした。